# Show that there is $x\in[-1;1]$ such as the set of limit point of $u_n(x)$ is $[-1;1]$ where $u_0(x) = x, u_{n+1}(x) = 2u_n(x)^2 - 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, metric-spaces

Let be $f$ defined by $f(x) = 2x^2 -1$.

Let be $(u_n(x))$ the sequence defined by: $u_0(x) = x, u_{n+1}(x) = f(u_n(x))$

Show that there is $x\in[-1;1]$ such as the set of limit point of $u_n(x)$ is $[-1;1]$.

I started with studying $f$ to find stable intervals, potential limits etc...
I've only found that $1$ and $-1/2$ are fixed point for $f$.
I don't know what to do next...

Comment: That's a problem of translation... I mean the set of point $y$ such as there is a $\phi$ increasing such as $u_{\phi(n)} (x)\to y $. Could you tell me what's the English name of it?

Comment: Good, that's what I thought. You mean the set of limits of all subsequences of $u_n$. And alternative formulation of the problem would be to say that $\{u_n(x) \mid n\in\mathbb{N},\, x\in[-1,1]\}$ is dense in $[-1,1]$. Thinking about it "limit point" or "accumulation point" is often used for this so I guess the problem is fine as written, just wanted to make sure I understoof it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $f\left(\left[-1,1\right]\right)=\left[-1,1\right]$.

**Update:** You can actually solve this recurrence. Note that $2\cos^{2}x-1=\cos2x$, and therefore it is easy to check that

$$u_{n}=\cos\left(2^{n}C\right)$$

is a solution, where $C$ is an arbitrary constant. In particular, if $u_{0}=x$ then $C=\arccos x$.

Comment: Ok, but I don't know what to do next.... I cannot see how to link it to the existance of such $x$.

Comment: Thanks for the update. So we must show that $\{2^n \times C + \pi k, n,k\in \Bbb N\}$ is dense in at lest $[0;2\pi]$ for a certain $C$.
I don't know how to find such a $C$; and even less how to show that it will be dense. (I'm sorry to don't manage to do it after all your hints, but it's the kind of maths I've most difficulties with...)